# json to django request

Tags: jquery, django, post, request

Trying to pass custom json data using jquery to django but django cannot receive data correctly.
data sample:

```
var data = {};
data.mylist = [{'a':'b'},{'a':'b'}];
data.myvar = 'something';
data.action = 'submit_invoice'
$.post(window.invoice_url, data, function(res){
    console.log(res)
});
```

Django view:

```
def foo(request):
    mylist = request.POST.getlist('mylist',None)
    myvar = request.POST.get('myvar', None)
    print(mylist)
    print(myvar)
    print(request.POST)
```

the print is something, [] and < QueryDict: {'action': ['submit_invoice'], 'mylist[1][a]': ['b'], 'myvar': ['something'], 'mylist[0][a]': ['b']} > and django cannot get mylist correctly.

Comment: What does `print (request.data['mylist'])` get you in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to send JSON, you should `stringify` the object you're passing, and also set the `dataType` to `json`:

```
$.post(window.invoice_url, JSON.stringify(data), function(res){
    console.log(res)
}, 'json');
```

In your Django view, you should then load the body of the request with `json.loads()`, after which you can access the attributes you want:

```
import json

def foo(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    mylist = data['mylist']
    myvar = data['myvar']
    print(mylist)
    print(myvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the js objects directly to url,

Use `v_data = jQuery.param(data)`, send `v_data` this with request.

The `param()` method creates a serialized representation of an array or an object that can be understandable by various frameworks like php, ruby, django etc.

For again converting it to python

```
from urllib import parse
value = parse.parse_qs(self.request.POST.get('v_name'))
```

Note that using prase you can lost some information, so recheck your data after getting it in python.